# I can't assign scripts to buttons in UNITY?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, scene

I just started exploring Unity and I'm making a game in UNITY 2D. 
I decided to start with a simple menu screen to get used to UNITY.
I made the menu and moved on to programming the buttons.

However when I drag the script (or the game object holding the script) in to the button on click section and try and select my function it does not show up.

My unity window
[image: my unity window]

Manager in the button on click script. 
[image]

My code in C#  (this is my first time using c#)
[image]

what I want to know is: have I done something wrong; doe unity work differently to how I understand it; is unity doing something weird; how do I fix it.

(appologies for the weird post layout I don't know why it did that).

Comment: Alex - check out [this tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-button) at around minute 9.

Comment: Voting to close as a typographical error, as the missing `;` has prevented Unity from compiling the new script so that it can be accessible in the inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert a `;` at the end of your code and you should be fine. You should notice that the compiler is complaining about the missing semicolon. Also, make sure to attach your script to the `_Manager` GameObject.

Answer (score 1):

You need to :

1. add a semi colon to the end of the line in the Buttons class
2. Add **Buttons** Class to the _Manager gameobject in the scene

Comment: If the script is on the `_Manager` GameObject, there shouldn't be any problem.